# relations between models AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, model

I've just started with using AngularJS for my webapplication it's very straightforward but now I can not continue.

I am making an application for a tire company.

This are my model relations:

Brand has 0 or more Brand Types (Models)
Tire has relates to one Brand and Brand type

I want to cache the Brands and releted Brand Types.

After I cache these arraylists in a controller I want to get the tires and make them link to the BrandType and the Brand.

These are my JSON files.

Brands

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Continental",
      "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
      "updated_at":"2015-07-15 20:45:35"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"Michelin",
      "created_at":"2015-07-15 21:03:56",
      "updated_at":"2015-07-17 12:14:05"
   }
]
```

The Brand Types relates to a Brand

```
{  
      "id":1,
      "name":"ContiSportContact3",
      "brand_id":1,
      "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
      "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"ContiSportContact4",
      "brand_id":1,
      "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
      "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "id":3,
      "name":"Pilot Alpin",
      "brand_id":2,
      "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
      "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
   }
]
```

Tires (has to be linked to a brand and brand type, because I need to show this in a table)

```
[  
   {  
      "id":3,
      "tire_number":1011,
      "brand_id":2,
      "brand_type_id":3,
      "category_id":1,
      "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
      "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
      "number":0,
      "width":225,
      "height":55,
      "diameter":16,
      "other":0,
      "load_factor":"95",
      "speed":"h",
      "mms":"6,5-7",
      "season_id":3
   }
]
```

I already have this and it's working but I need to show the brand name and brand type name instead of the ID.

```
  <tr ng-repeat="tire in tires">
                    <td><%tire.tire_number%></td>
                    <td><%tire.brand_id%></td>
                    <td><%tire.brand_type_id%></td>
                    <td><%tire.season_id%></td>

                    <td><%tire.width%></td>
                    <td><%tire.height%></td>
                    <td><%tire.diameter%><%tire.other%></td>
                    <td><%tire.load_factor%></td>
                    <td><%tire.speed%></td>
                    <td><%tire.mms%></td>

                </tr>
```

It should be easy probably but I've searched a lot and I could not find a straightforward solution.

Comment: created_at and updated_at indicate that you're apparently use ORM. Did you consider setting up relations there and supply Angular with ready to use data? It is much more straighforward.

Comment: Yes that could be a solution, but I find it a beter way to load these from a cached list because I need to load the Brands and brand types anyway because of select boxes in my webpage.

Comment: I'll now look into this: https://github.com/psgibbs/angular-relational this looks like it's doing the thing I want to accomplish

Comment: @estus I think I'll go with your solution. But it would be interesting though how it could be maked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively easy to convert your Brands array into a hashmap using the ID as keys which you can then use for very simple lookup of names based on the `brand_id` of each tire

```
$scope.brandNames = {};
brandData.forEach(function(item) {
  $scope.brandNames[item.id] = item.name
});
```

Would produce:

```
{  
  1:"Continental",
  2:"Michelin"
}
```

Then in the view you can do:

```
 <td>{{brandNames[tire.brand_id]}}</td>
```

[Demo using service to pass hashmap to controller](http://plnkr.co/edit/B8rjRvC9DqbmO5lUgeDi?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll look into this when I'm working on this project again! If it works I'll accept it.

Comment: Wow very cool that you made a demo! I've accepted your answer!